# Identification of the most relevant vertices of a 2D polygon

Tags: algorithm, polygon

I've been researching for a known algorithm that identifies the "most relevant" vertices of a 2D polygon. I may be using the wrong keywords (I've been trying to search for mesh simplification algorithms), but I've not yet found anything useful.

I should define what I mean by "most relevant" vertices with some context. I want to take a 2D polygon, apply a geometrical transformation, and render both the pre-transformed and post-transformed polygons with a mapping between the vertices to visualize the effects of the transformation. However, with small highly detailed polygons (high vertex count per area), there is a lot of "visual clutter".

The idea is that there should be an algorithm that could identify which vertices would be eligible for mapping and which ones wouldn't. I can design such an algorithm by taking into account two things:

1. Edge length: ignore a vertex if the length between it and the previous one is smaller than a threshold. An accumulator would be needed to avoid ignoring multiple subsequent vertices.
2. Internal angle: ignore a vertex if the internal angle at the vertex is higher than a threshold. An "accumulator" would be needed to avoid ignoring multiple subsequent vertices.

Despite probably being able to implement such a thing, I don't like reinventing the wheel and decided to ask you if you came across something like this which could actually solve other problems that I didn't think of (e.g., complex polygons).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm, which does "path simplification" but can be extended for use with polygons. It works by starting with only a couple of endpoints, then greedily adding back whichever vertices are necessary to approximate the original shape to within a certain tolerance. There are a variety of other algorithms and heuristics, but none of them has a reputation for reliably producing significantly better results than RDP, and RDP is easy to understand and implement.

Comment: While researching I found this algorithm. However, since it uses the maximum distance to simplify vertices I don't know if it will work as I need. I'll probably implement it and test it since it does look promising from the examples.